# Kernel and functional testing with an MSSQL database

Tags: database, 9, testing

I am new to testing custom modules.  My custom modules create and update custom nodes.  From my reading, I need to use Kernel or Functional tests to test these operations.  My Drupal 9 installation is on Windows Server with IIS and Microsoft SQL Server.

All the testing examples seem to use `mysql` in their `phpunit.xml` config.  I must use the `sqlsrv` driver module to have Drupal communicate with the MSSQL database.  When I try and use  `sqlsrv` in my `phpunit.xml` `SIMPLETEST_DB` connection key, I get a database connection error when running the test.

My `phpunit.xml` database line:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="sqlsrv://username:password@localhost/database_name"/>
```

The error I get:

```
InvalidArgumentException : Can not convert 'sqlsrv://username:password@localhost/database_name to a database connection, class 'Drupal\Driver\Database\sqlsrv\Connection' does not exist
```

Is a MSSQL database server not compatible with the testing environment created for Drupal?  Can I only use MySQL?

***Followup question:***

Something I didn't get from my reading, should a second database be used just for testing since it will be creating and deleting info?  If that's the case, could I use a MySQL database just for testing?

Comment: And you followed this? https://git.drupalcode.org/project/sqlsrv/-/blob/4.3.x/README.md?ref_type=heads  and reviewed the tests in that module for examples?